# Displaying form data with php and laravel

Tags: php, database, forms, sqlite, laravel

HI there I am trying to get form data to be stored in a database and then show that data as an object on the webpage. I am then wanting to be able to edit that object's data and update the database with the new information.

Like a comments/post section on a blog/facebook

Thanks for any help you can offer the specifics/ what i currently have is below. I am using laravel 4.2  and sqlite to manage everything. I think the issue is with my routes though.

Have a great day.

This is my directory layout

```html
- app

-- database
---posts.sql
---comments.sql

-- views
--- layouts
------- default.blade.php
--- pages
------- home.blade.php
------- edit.blade.php
--- includes
------- head.blade.php
------- header.blade.php
------- footer.blade.php

--routes.php
```

I currently have two databases that I am trying to interact with add/edit/delete rows.

Both follow this format

```html
/* Posts database in SQLite. */
drop table if exists posts;

create table posts (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  number int, /* 0 = subsequent term */
  post_username varchar(40) not null,
  post_title varchar(40),
  post varchar(140)
);

/* Column names changed to avoid SQLite reserved words. */

insert into posts(number, post_username, post_title, post) values (1,'First Poster', 'first title', 'first');
insert into posts(number, post_username, post_title, post) values (2,'Second Poster', 'second title', 'second post');
/* Sample query to test insertion worked. */

select * from posts
where post_title like "%first%"
order by id;
```

And I want to be able to display current information in the .sql file(s) on the home page using tables like so whilst also adding to the page with a new form.

```html
@section('title') Home Page
@stop

@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')


<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>


<!-- Form Name -->
  <form method="get" action="add_post">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Post Username: </td><td><input type="text" name="post_username"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Post Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="post_title"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Post: </td><td><input type="text" name="post"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="add_post">
                      <input type="reset" value="Reset"></td></tr>
  <table>
  </form>
  
@if (count($posts) == 0)

<p>No Current Posts</p>
  
  <table class="bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>No.</th><th>Post Username</th><th>Post Title</th><th>Post</th></tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  
@foreach($posts as $post)

  <tr><td>{{{ $post->number }}}</td><td>{{{ $post->post_username }}}</td><td>{{{ $post->post_title }}}</td><td>{{{ $post->post }}}</td></tr>

@endforeach  

@stop
```

But it doesn't work I don't know why.

Please help multimedia nerd who picked up a web-programming course and is just realizing the mistake :)

**Routes page:**

```html
<?php

  $post_username = Input::get('post_username');
  $post_title = Input::get('post_title');
  $post = Input::get('post'); 
  
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('pages.home');
});

Route::get('/comments', function()
{
return View::make('pages.comments');
});

/*
 Currently crashing website
Route::get('add_post', function()
{
  $sql = "insert into posts (post_username, post_title, post) values (?, ?, ?)";
  DB::insert($sql, array($post_username, $post_title, $post));
});

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you routes to this:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('pages.home');
});

Route::get('/comments', function()
{
return View::make('pages.comments');
});

// Currently crashing website
Route::get('add_post', function()
{
  $post_username = Input::get('post_username');
  $post_title = Input::get('post_title');
  $post = Input::get('post'); 

  $sql = "insert into posts (post_username, post_title, post) values (?, ?, ?)";
  DB::insert($sql, array($post_username, $post_title, $post));
});
```

and, instead of doing save logic inside route you should write that in controller. There are some good tutorial like [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/lessons) and [Culttt](http://culttt.com/tag/cribbb/page/11/), kindly visit them and change your approach. See, if that helps.

Comment: HI there, thanks for your reply, however this still does not add anything to the database.

Comment: Have you added required fields corresponding to database connection in database.php file?

Comment: under controllers folder?

Comment: don't do it in controller, there is a file in app/config folder named as database.php, Update that.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I really do have very little idea what I am looking at. There is a statement                                                            'default' => 'sqlite',

Is that What I am after?

Comment: yes, change that to mysql and enter other details like user name, password for your mysql and your db name.

Comment: it is an assessment and it is supposed to be in sqlite3. There are no passwords/logins just generic usernames and titles that are just stings in an array of arrays. I just want to be able to add and display them in a table

Comment: I have less info regarding sqlite, coz I have used mysql and mongodb with laravel.